# Python does not like ruby json

Tags: python, ruby, json

I save the below as json in ruby

```
File.open("/tmp/zookeeper_hosts","w") do |f|
  f.write(zk_hosts.to_json)
end


{
    "zookeeper_hosts": [
        "127.0.0.1"
    ]
}
```

Oh my....in python

```
    zk_host_list = json.loads('/tmp/zookeeper_hosts')

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/forex-master/zookeeper_test/zookeeper_service.py", line 12, in <module>
        zk_host_list = json.loads('/tmp/zookeeper_hosts')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
        raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) and send in the file object.

[`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) is for a string or unicode.

Example -

```
import json
with open('/tmp/zookeeper_hosts') as f:
    zk_host_list = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before reading the contents of the file, open it:

```
with open('/tmp/zookeeper_hosts') as f:
    zk_host_list = json.loads(f.read())
```